# Starting a newline in the list structure

Tags: lists

The following code

```
\begin{description}
\item[\emph{Initialization Step}] 
 Let $\varepsilon > 0$ be a termination tolerance. Choose an initial point $\theta^{(1)}$. Let $X^{(1)} = (0, 0, 0, 0, \ldots, 0,   \theta^{(1)T})^T$, $j = 1$ and go to the Main Step. 

\item[\emph{Main Step}] 
\begin{enumerate}
\item For given $\theta^{(j)}$, solve the linear program \eqref{LP} to get $\hat{\xi}^{(j + 1)} = \hat{\xi}$.
\item Substitute $\hat{\xi}^{(j + 1)}$ into \eqref{mainproblem}, solve the resulting nonlinear program to get $\hat{\theta}^{(j + 1)}$. Form $X^{(j + 1)} = (\hat{\xi}^{(j + 1)T}, \hat{\theta}^{(j + 1)T})^T$. If $\|X^{(j + 1)} - X^{(j)}\| < \varepsilon$, stop; otherwise, replace $j$ by $j + 1$, and go to step 1.
\end{enumerate}
\end{description}
```

gives the output below:
[image]
which is not the desired one I want. The output that I exactly want should be there are no words appear in the same line with the itemize tags. For example, "Let $\varepsilon > 0$..." should be right below the "Initialization Step" (with some indent is also desirable). Is there any easy way to fulfill this? Thank you very much.

Comment: ``\item[Initialization Step]\mbox{}\\``

Comment: OK, this works perfectly for the first item. However, when I tried the same trick after `Main Step`, it produces a large vertical space, how to deal with that?

Comment: In the second one you don't add ``\\``

Comment: This really should be done using the `nextline` style in [enumitem](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem), but there seems to be a problem using this with nested lists...see [Problem using enumitem's nextline style with nested lists](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/290136/problem-using-enumitems-nextline-style-with-nested-lists)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this is using a `description` environment together with tweaks from the [enumitem](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) package. Unfortunately, there is an issue using nested lists with [enumitem](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem)'s `style=nextline` but Bernard has given a fix in [Problem using enumitem's nextline style with nested lists](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/290136/problem-using-enumitems-nextline-style-with-nested-lists/290145#290145).

Another benefit of using [enumitem](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) is that you can control the formatting of the labels.

Here is the output from the MWE below:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newif\ifInDescription\InDescriptionfalse% 
\newcommand\NestingFix{% if inside Description force line break
  \ifInDescription%
    \leavevmode\vspace*{-\dimexpr2\topsep+\baselineskip\relax}%
  \fi%
}
\newlist{algorithm}{description}{1}
\setlist[algorithm]{style=nextline,% each label on its own line
                    before=\InDescriptiontrue,% starting Description
                    after=\InDescriptionfalse,% leaving Description
                    font=\itshape\bfseries% set font for labels
}
\setlist{before=\NestingFix}% apply nesting fix to all list environments

\begin{document}

  \begin{algorithm}
    \item[Initialization Step]
      Let $\varepsilon > 0$ be a termination tolerance. Choose an
      initial point $\theta^{(1)}$. Let $X^{(1)} = (0, 0, 0, 0,
      \ldots, 0,   \theta^{(1)T})^T$, $j = 1$ and go to the Main
      Step.

    \item[Main Step]
      \begin{enumerate}
        \item For given $\theta^{(j)}$, solve the linear program
          \eqref{LP} to get $\hat{\xi}^{(j + 1)} = \hat{\xi}$.
        \item Substitute $\hat{\xi}^{(j + 1)}$ into
          \eqref{mainproblem}, solve the resulting nonlinear program to
          get $\hat{\theta}^{(j + 1)}$. Form $X^{(j + 1)} =
          (\hat{\xi}^{(j + 1)T}, \hat{\theta}^{(j + 1)T})^T$. If
          $\|X^{(j + 1)} - X^{(j)}\| < \varepsilon$, stop; otherwise,
          replace $j$ by $j + 1$, and go to step 1.
      \end{enumerate}
  \end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @Andrew: If I may suggest, I would add to the nested enumerate one of the options `[wide=0pt]` or `[labelindent= 0pt, align= left, labelsep=0.4em, leftmargin=*]`, so the numbering starts at the left margin of the description environment.

Comment: @Bernard Is there a way of adding these dynamically? The whole point of using the `\ifInDescription` flag was that I wanted nested environments to work without any (obvious) modifications.