# Problem using enumitem's nextline style with nested lists

Tags: enumitem

The [enumitem](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) package has a `style=nextline` option that can be used to make labels in `description` environments sit on their own line. This works really well unless you want to nest `description`, `itemize` or `enumerate` environments when it fails and produces:

[image]

To try and fix this I have tried playing around with the [enumitem](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) options and doing things like putting `\newline`, ``` \quad``\hfil ```, `\hss`, ... after the `\item[...]` command but I have not found anything that works and most of the time these "fixes" result in an extra blank line appearing between the item line and the nested environment.

The same thing happen with nested `description` and `enumerate` environments. Can anyone see how to fix this?

Here is a MWE exhibiting the problem.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}

  \begin{description}[style=nextline]
    \item[First item] Some text
    \item[Second item] Some text
    \item[Third item]\hfill
      \begin{itemize}
        \item Nested itemise
        \item Nested itemise
      \end{itemize}
    \item[Fourth item] Some text
  \end{description}

\end{document}
```

**EDIT**

One manual hack that does fix the problem is putting `\hfil` after the `\item[...]` command and then adding `\vskip-6mm` after the next item. It's not exactly elegant and it would be better to find a solution using the tools provided by `enumitem`. Here's the hack:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}

  \begin{description}[style=nextline]
    \item[First item] Some text
    \item[Second item] Some text
    \item[Third item]\hfil
      \begin{itemize}
        \item \vskip-6mm Nested itemise
        \item Nested itemise
      \end{itemize}
    \item[Fourth item] Some text
  \end{description}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is such a solution (I think):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{description}[style=nextline]
  \item[First item] Some text
  \item[Second item] Some text
  \item[Third item]%
  \begin{itemize}[before=\leavevmode\vspace*{-\dimexpr2\topsep + \baselineskip\relax}]
    \item Nested itemise
    \item Nested itemise
  \end{itemize}
  \item[Fourth item] Some text
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Bernard! I have used a more automated version of this to answer [Starting a newline in the list structure](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/289975/starting-a-newline-in-the-list-structure/290163#290163).